# What is System Restore in Windows operating systems?

Tags: windows, restore, system-restore

What is System Restore in Windows operating systems?

Comment: Comments deleted as noise. The **correct** method of handling these question is the one used by [mehper](http://superuser.com/questions/207020/what-is-system-restore-in-windows-operating-system/207024#207024). If Wikipedia should no longer exist the content is preserved here, and this has happened with a few sites in the past. If this is to be debated further, please take it to [MSE](http://meta.superuser.com)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **System Restore** is a component of
>   Microsoft's Windows Me, Windows XP,
>   Windows Vista and Windows 7 operating
>   systems that allows for the rolling
>   back of system files, registry keys,
>   installed programs, etc., to a
>   previous state in the event of system
>   malfunction or failure.
>
> In System Restore, the user may create
>   a new restore point manually, roll
>   back to an existing restore point, or
>   change the System Restore
>   configuration. Moreover, the restore
>   itself can be undone. Old restore
>   points are discarded in order to keep
>   the volume's usage within the
>   specified amount. For many users, this
>   can provide restore points covering
>   the past several weeks. Users
>   concerned with performance or space
>   usage may also opt to disable System
>   Restore entirely. Files stored on
>   volumes not monitored by System
>   Restore are never backed up or
>   restored.
>
> System Restore backs up system files
>   of certain extensions (`.exe`, `.dll`,
>   etc.) and saves them for later
>   recovery and use. It also backs up the
>   registry and most drivers.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Restore)